# Company declined offer after i left old company

Tags: hiring

I was selected in a company and they forward a portal to enter my details including education details and after 3 days they sent a offer letter through email and I accepted the same. I left the old company and went for 1st day formalities to new company but they kept my offer letter hard copy on hold and told that they have some doubt on my Degree certificates. Now i'm job less. Please advise what action should I take now

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: The only answer other than "it sucks but you have to move on" is a legal one so I'm a fraid this is off-topic.

Comment: First action, start looking for a new job. If you left your old job gracefully, ask them if they would consider taking you back. If they haven't filled the position, they might.

Comment: Are your degrees valid?

Comment: You don't necessarily need legal advice here, but some common sense. If your degree is genuine, then resolve all their concerns by (for example) getting them to contact your University directly. If your degree is fake, there really isn't any question here.

Answer (score 4):

Go to a lawyer... Cannot think of anything else based on what I have read. If they had any doubts they should have expressed them before offering you the position in the first place.

Validate first your legal options first, then you will be able to have a number of possibilities to see which one you should pursue.

Comment: I'm not sure what a lawyer could do to help. A company has every right to rescind an offer letter.

Comment: @DavidK That may depend on the country.

Comment: @DavidK They may not or they may have some liablity... which is why you consult a lawyer to find out your legal options.

Comment: @DavidK While we're heading into a legal discussion it's indeed the case that in some countries offer letters are the same as contracts and have legal power. The very act of creating one can constitute a binding offer to employ someone and legal shenanigans can ensue if they eventually refuse to hire the person.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do is to find out what their concern is, and see if you can clear it up, perhaps by having transcripts sent directly to them. If it is a resolvable misunderstanding, that gets you a job without needing a lawyer.